# Server Error in '/' Application.Connection string error.. provider name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hello I am getting this error and can't seem to figure out what may be wrong.

> CS1061: 'ASP.manager_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' and no extension method 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.manager_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

this is what the datasource looks like

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRegistration" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>" 
        OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [usertable1]">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my web config looks like this

```
connectionStrings>
    <add name="RegistrationConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(.\sqlexpress)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Registration.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Could someone please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: And where is the calling code?

Answer (score 1):

In your codebehind you have to add something like:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: ok i add it but after compilation i got another error ...Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.